# Assignment Branch Condition is too high

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My code is:

```
def send_deliverer_push_notification(order_fulfillment, parse_events)
shopper_id               = order_fulfillment.shopper_id
order                = Order.find_by(id: order_fulfillment_id)
user_id              = order.user_id
role_name            = Shopper.find_by(id: shopper_id).roles.pluck(:name).first
batch_id             = Batch.find_by(shopper_id: shopper_id).id
message              = "Order # #{order_fulfillment.order_id} is now ready for pick-up"

ParseHelpers.publish_batching_status(user_id, *parse_events, message) do
    {
    shopper_id:   shopper_id,
    role:     role_name,
    task:     order_fulfillment.shopper_status,
    batch_id: batch_id,
    fulfillment_number: "#{order.order_number}-#{order_fulfillment.store_id}"
    }
    end
  end
```

and I get `Assignment Branch Condition size for send_deliverer_push_notification is too high. [16.16/15]`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you use to get that report?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Hound

Answer (score 2):

From your example it is clear you don't need many of the intermediary variables and therefore assignments. All the parameters building code that is actually necessary should be moved to a separate method:

```
def send_deliverer_push_notification(order_fulfillment, parse_events)
  order = Order.find_by(id: order_fulfillment_id)
  message = "Order # #{order_fulfillment.order_id} is now ready for pick-up"

  ParseHelpers.publish_batching_status(order.user_id, *parse_events, message) do
    batching_status_params(order, order_fulfillment)
  end
end

def batching_status_params(order, order_fulfillment)
  {
    shopper_id: order_fulfillment.shopper_id,
    role: Shopper.find_by(id: order_fulfillment.shopper_id).roles.pluck(:name).first,
    task: order_fulfillment.shopper_status,
    batch_id: Batch.find_by(shopper_id: order_fulfillment.shopper_id).id,
    fulfillment_number: "#{order.order_number}-#{order_fulfillment.store_id}"
  }
end
```

But it's better to worry about code conciseness and readability, not a score. The score can be a good way to spot places that require attention. It is in no way an objective measure of the code quality.

Looking at this example, it is clearly too verbose and is not very good on the separation of concerns aspect. This line:

```
role: Shopper.find_by(id: order_fulfillment.shopper_id).roles.pluck(:name).first
```

Should probably be better expressed as a `Shopper` method like this:

```
class Shopper < ...
  ...

  def self.role_of(shopper_id)
    find_by(id: shopper_id).roles.pluck(:name).first
  end
end
```

Then you could replace that line with a much more readable

```
role: Shopper.role_of(order_fulfillment.shopper_id)
```

Something similar could be done with this line:

```
Batch.find_by(shopper_id: order_fulfillment.shopper_id).id
```

The logic could be placed to an `OrderFullfillment`'s method.

Following this approach you could reach a point where your code would consist of smaller building blocks, easily combinable as needed. There are other benefits to this approach such as better testability and potential readability. Be careful not to go to the opposite extent and make every line a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

you have to move away

```
shopper_id               = order_fulfillment.shopper_id
order                = Order.find_by(id: order_fulfillment_id)
user_id              = order.user_id
role_name            = Shopper.find_by(id: shopper_id).roles.pluck(:name).first
batch_id             = Batch.find_by(shopper_id: shopper_id).id
message              = "Order # #{order_fulfillment.order_id} is now ready for pick-up"
```

to to separate method or even couple methods and set it as attributes

same for `ParseHelpers.publish_batching_status`

Comment: This piece of advice is questionable. Blindly moving code around to satisfy automated metric rarely results in better code. Instead, one must move code intentionally and with good justification ("improving flog score" doesn't count) :)

Comment: flog score is an _approximation_ of code complexity. One should reduce complexity, not flog score.

Comment: I've seen many examples of "refactorings" when code became perfectly green on codeclimate, but in reality it went from a couple  of compact medium-sized methods to a gigantic mess of one-liner methods and one-liner classes. Much harder to grasp.